# Clarification: Neo4j ogm Session API returning 0 instances for countEntitiesOfType for builtin model types

Tags: neo4j-ogm

I am using neo4j-ogm-core version 2.1.2 with neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver version 2.1.2 and able to query user defined models using session. However when executing the following lines of code for built in types( NodeModel & RelationshipModel) the API returns 0 instances.

```
System.out.println("count(NodeModel) :   "+session.countEntitiesOfType(NodeModel.class));
System.out.println("count(RelationshipModel) : "+session.countEntitiesOfType(RelationshipModel.class));
```

Is it expected result for builtin types or some additional configuration is required for looking up concrete realization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NodeModel` and `RelationshipModel` are internal OGM infrastructure classes. They cannot be used for querying.

If you want to have a global count of nodes and relationships in Neo4j, you can use custom queries like :
`MATCH (n) return count(n)` or `MATCH ()-[r]-() RETURN count(r)`

Comment: Thanks, one can live with the query alternatives as workaround. From OOAD extension point of view of graph modeling, some alternative of the NodeModel/ RelationshipModel as discoverable realization in future releases would be good to have feature.